# Windows Store App obfuscation with .NetReactor

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, obfuscation

I have windows store application, which i trying to obfuscate with .NetReactor. I have read a lot of information, but i can't figure out how i can create Windows Store package with obfuscated code.

I tried to obfuscate through Reactor application my dll's, but i dont understand what i should do next. It is created \secure folder, where placed new dll.

Some i am wondered, should i some how create package with this dll, or is there some way to obfuscate already created .appxupload files?
If someone can give me a tip or link for more information, i would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution in installing VS plugin of .NetReactor, where i have set settings for obfuscation of some libraries, and then when i have created new store package, plugin working in this proccess and obfuscated code in prepared package.